# Abrir layout especifico dentro de un ViewFlipper

Tags: android

Estoy haciendo un menú, y quiero que cada botón abra un layout diferente que están dentro de un `ViewFlipper`.
Es decir, que según el botón que seleccione en el menu el `ViewFlipper` comience con ese layout seleccionado.

Cuando estoy dentro del activity que maneja el `ViewFlipper` si puedo cambiarlos usando `setDisplayedChild`, pero eso no puedo usarlo en la página del menú.
¿Como puedo hacerlo?

```
<ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/viewFlipper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  >
    <include layout="@layout/pagina1"/>
    <include layout="@layout/pagina2"/>
    <include layout="@layout/pagina3"/>
    <include layout="@layout/pagina4"/>
    <include layout="@layout/pagina5"/>

</ViewFlipper>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para que cada "pagina" se pueda cambiar usa el método `onTouchEvent()` con el cual puedes detectar un desplazamiento en el eje X, y de esta forma mostrar los layouts contenidos en los `include`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
    private float lastX;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewflipper);

    }


    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent) {
        switch (touchevent.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
            lastX = touchevent.getX();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
            float currentX = touchevent.getX();

            if (lastX < currentX) {
                if (viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 0)
                    break;
                //Adelante.
                viewFlipper.showNext();
             }

             if (lastX > currentX) {
                 if (viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 1)
                     break;
                 //Atras.
                 viewFlipper.showPrevious();
             }
             break;
         }
         return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pero a ver no me as entendido bien, eso ya lo tengo, lo que yo quiero es abrir el viewFlipper por el layout que yo quiera desde la página del inicio.

Comment: Te refieres a que deseas abrir el viewFlipper desde el layout definido en el include?

Comment: quiero hacer un startActivity(i); de la página que contiene el viewflipper pero que esta no habra el layout por defecto que es el primero sino el que yo indique como con la accion setDisplayedChild